Why are METAR issued at 53 minutes of the hour?
Why are METAR routinely issued at 53 past the hour, not at "o’clock"?

In short
H:53' is a pretty uncommon schedule, typically used for US METAR. It's an organizational choice: The weather stations, contributing to several weather reports, are fully dedicated to US METAR issuance for a period of 6 minutes each hour, from H:47:20 to H:53:20. The stations observations are then used by prediction applications issuing their own results at the top of the hour.

General case
From WMO Aerodrome Reports and Forecasts:

A METAR is issued at hourly or half-hourly intervals

Apart for the frequency, there is no precise schedule. In practical there is a variety of timings:

LFPG: Charles de Gaulle International Airport, H+00' and H+30'.
EGLL: London Heathrow Airport, H+20' and H+50'.
KLAX: Los Angeles International Airport, H+53'

Aviation weather reports are often provided by automated systems, ASOS (mostly aviation data) and AWOS (aviation and additional data). Automated reports are normally identified by the word 'AUTO' after the issuance time. In this case the period is likely constant. However WMO, the international weather organization, another UN agency working with ICAO for the weather topics, sets no general rule.
ASOS and AWOS stations typically update their observations at one- or five-minute, intervals. METAR are not updated so quickly, but results can be transmitted at this frequency using UAT (more).
US specific case at 53'
53', 54', 55' and 56' are typical of US METAR issuance time. The reason is the ASOS stations perform observations and prepare different reports but are fully dedicated to METAR from H+47:20 to H+53:20:

Starting at 47 minutes and 20 seconds past the hour, the ASOS begins to make its routine observation. By 53 minutes and 20 seconds after the hour, the observation has been prepared and edited and should be ready for transmission. Many of the hourly METARs will carry an issuance time of 53, 54, 55 or 56 minutes past the hour.


This period of time between 47:20 and 53:20 minutes after the hour is known as the “lockout period.” During this period, the ASOS is prevented from issuing any other reports, including special reports (SPECIs), no matter what weather may be occurring. The ASOS still continuously monitors and records the weather during the lockout period; it just can’t issue a surface observation

Source. This is confirmed by a NTSB report using the same wording:

The ASOS transmits an official meteorological aerodrome report (known as a METAR) at 53 minutes past each hour and a special weather observation (known as a SPECI) as conditions warrant; such conditions include a wind shift, change in visibility, and change in ceiling (cloud cover or height). The system is prevented from issuing any reports between 47:20 and 53:20 after the hour (known as the lockout period) so that the hourly
observation can be prepared, edited, and transmitted.

An ASOS at Borger, Texas:

Source.

In the US, METARs being issued at :53 (and also as needed for significant changes) is nearly universal. You may see an hourly observation at :50 or :55 or some other minute, but it’s pretty uncommon. What has driven that standard of :53 is an interesting question.

In Canada, METARs are

taken every
hour on the hour at over 200 aerodromes and other locations in
Canada.

E.g.:
METAR CYUL 280100Z 01006KT 15SM SKC 17/12 A3002 RMK SLP169=
METAR CYUL 280000Z 35003KT 15SM FEW250 17/12 A3001 RMK CI1 SLP166=
METAR CYUL 272300Z 31002KT 15SM FEW100 SCT250 18/12 A3001 RMK AC2CI2 SLP166 DENSITY ALT 500FT=
METAR CYUL 272200Z 36004KT 15SM FEW040 FEW120 FEW250 19/12 A3000 RMK SC1AC1CI1 SC TR CI TR SLP162 DENSITY ALT 600FT=
METAR CYUL 272100Z 34003KT 270V350 15SM FEW035 FEW040 FEW250 20/12 A3000 RMK CF1SC1CI1 CF TR CI TR SLP160 DENSITY ALT 700FT=
METAR CYUL 272000Z 31005KT 220V340 15SM FEW035 SCT040 SCT250 20/12 A3000 RMK CF1SC2CI1 CI TR SLP163 DENSITY ALT 700FT=
METAR CYUL 271900Z 34008KT 15SM SCT040 SCT250 20/11 A3000 RMK SC4CI1 CI TR SLP162 DENSITY ALT 700FT=

In the U.S.,

The METAR is a scheduled observation between 45 and 59 minutes past the hour.

But practice can vary.

This does not seem to answer why the METAR is issued in this time range (which was the question). It only confirms that it's normal in the US.

53 happens to be smack-dab in the middle of 45 and 00. Well - off by 30 seconds.
